# How to get the first img tag from string

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to get a the first img tag only and store it into a string, so far I have a string, which stores all the below html. How would I extract the first img tag only. Im using java to do this.

```
Hello this is <b>BOLD&nbsp;<br></b>
<img src=\"boot.jpg">
<img src=\"Shirt.jpg">
<img src=\"gloves.jpg">
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with a `Matcher` and only get the first match.

```
(<img .*?>)
```

Like this:

```
String text = "Your text";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<img .*?>)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
    // do something with matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: It's giving me the string of all the img's. Maybe I im doing something wrong shouldn't:  String img1  = matcher.group(1); give me only the first img?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the pattern for lazy instead of greedy (the question mark after the star).